# Pivot Data with Duplicate Keys

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[image]

I am trying to pivot the MW column values into separate columns.

It would be something like: Buy Round Off-peak Fall 2016 and 10 columns of the MW values

Buy Round 1 Off-peak    Fall    2016    35593.9 35593.9 16430   15930   13891.5 12424   9730    8756    7730.5  7298    6685.4

How would I do this in python or excel?

Comment: I don't think I understood what you're trying to get at. Can you share desired outcome for this data. Please use markdown table to share data, so we don't need to retype from scratch:  https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: either aggregate with `pivot_table` or de-duplicate (see #10 in dupe link)